# Why concurrency contention tool in vs 2010 doesn't use managed thread ids?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, concurrency, profiler, contention

If you have used the concurrency contention profile tool provided in vs 2010, you will notice that all the thread ids used in the report are not managed thread ids, which is annoying. I want to know which thread is which one and how can I easily map those thread ids (usually a 4-digit id) used in the report against the ManagedThreadID value I can get from the code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'Collect resource contention data' option (see below), then you will be able to see the managed threads with their names. [image: Concurrency]

This is described on [John Robbin's blog](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/10/19/vs-2010-beta-2-concurrency-resource-profiling-in-depth-first-look.aspx) and may be enough to help you identify the managed threads. Unfortunately you can't get the mapping back to the managed thread IDs.